# Include external libraries into CLion project through CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, libraries, clion, glfw

I struggle to get GLFW **Windows pre-compiled binaries** working within my CLion Project. Those libraries are placed in a external directory. I **do not want** them to be in my project library but should (of course) be shipped when releasing the application. I am new to C++ but I thought to accomplish this might be as easy as it is in Java (Intellij Idea -> dependencies -> ...).

[GLFW Windows pre-compiled binaries](http://www.glfw.org/download.html)

I use MinGW 5.0 and CMake 3.10.2;
My CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(Hatsudouki_core)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

link_directories(F:\\C++\\ExternalLibraries\\GLFW\\lib-mingw-w64)
include_directories(F:\\C++\\ExternalLibraries\\GLFW\\include)

add_executable(Hatsudouki_core main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(Hatsudouki_core glfw3)
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main() {
    if (!glfwInit())
         std::cout << "error!" << std::endl;
    else
         std::cout << "success!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Build output

```
"F:\C++\CLion 2018.1\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\Users\simon\CLionProjects\Hatsudouki-core\cmake-build-debug --target Hatsudouki_core -- -j 4
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable Hatsudouki_core.exe
CMakeFiles\Hatsudouki_core.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `main':
C:/Users/simon/CLionProjects/Hatsudouki-core/main.cpp:5: undefined reference to `glfwInit'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [Hatsudouki_core.exe] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Hatsudouki_core.dir\build.make:96: recipe for target 'Hatsudouki_core.exe' failed
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:66: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Hatsudouki_core.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Hatsudouki_core.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:78: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Hatsudouki_core.dir/rule' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Hatsudouki_core.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'Hatsudouki_core' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Hatsudouki_core] Error 2
```

I tried following solutions mentioned here:
- [GLFW doc](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/build_guide.html#build_link_cmake_package) and [GLFW doc2](http://www.glfw.org/docs/3.0/build.html) (find package does not work, no CMake file)
- [Github issue report](https://github.com/glfw/website/issues/45) related to [Github issue report 2](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues/634) which then leads to the solution to put [FindGLFW.cmake](https://github.com/andrewrk/genesis/blob/master/cmake/FindGLFW.cmake) into some directory? Tried to put it here `GLFW\FindGLFW.cmake` but does not work
- Linking did not work as well as mentioned here: [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774593/cmake-link-to-external-library)

Image GLFW directory: [GLFW Windows pre-compiled binaries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbfmB.jpg)

I think I just do not understand how CMake, external Libraries and C++ work together to accomplish this fairly easy task. I believe comparison to Java would help (used to work with gradle)

**EDIT 1**
As suggested I added following:
I put the `Findglfw3.cmake` into `PROJECT/cmake/Modules/`:

```
# Copyright (c) 2015 Andrew Kelley
# This file is MIT licensed.
# See http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT

# GLFW_FOUND
# GLFW_INCLUDE_DIR
# GLFW_LIBRARY

find_path(GLFW_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES F:\\C++\\ExternalLibraries\\GLFW\\include\\GLFW\\glfw3.h)

find_library(GLFW_LIBRARY NAMES glfw glfw3)

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
find_package_handle_standard_args(GLFW DEFAULT_MSG GLFW_LIBRARY GLFW_INCLUDE_DIR)

mark_as_advanced(GLFW_INCLUDE_DIR GLFW_LIBRARY)
```

And added following lines into my CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${glfw3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set(LIBS ${LIBS} ${glfw3_LIBRARIES})
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules/")

target_link_libraries(hatsudouki_core ${LIBS})
```

I also tried in the Findglfw3.cmake:

```
find_path(GLFW_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES GLFW/glfw3.h)
```

which is the same in the original file. Both do not work; error:

```
"F:\C++\CLion 2018.1\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\Users\simon\CLionProjects\Hatsudouki-core\cmake-build-debug --target Hatsudouki_core -- -j 4
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package):
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
By not providing "Findglfw3.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
See also "C:/Users/simon/CLionProjects/Hatsudouki-core/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "glfw3", but
CMake did not find one.

Makefile:175: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "glfw3" with any of
the following names:

glfw3Config.cmake
glfw3-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "glfw3" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"glfw3_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "glfw3"
provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
installed.
mingw32-make.exe: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
```

Comment: C++ linking and Java are two *very* different things. Trying to compare them will only confuse you further. Your `CMakeLists.txt` hardwires paths; this should not be done. You should put `FindGLFW.cmake` to where CMake can find it (e.g. by adding the directory where you put it to `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`), and then use the CMake command `find_package( GLFW )`. Generally speaking, your question is a lot of questions, and thus a bit hard to answer appropriately...

Comment: Your CMakeLists.txt file is missing `find_package(glfw3)` and in the `target_link_libraries` call you need to reference `glfw`. You might need to add the path to the glfw3 library to your `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`. See http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/build_guide.html#build_link_cmake_source for further information.

Comment: Actually, the CMake code seems to be OK (it is not *perfect*, as it uses hardcoded paths instead of `find_package()`, but it should work). Error "undefined reference to 'glfwInit'" means that: 1. GLFW header files have been found. 2. GLFW library has been found. 3. The library doesn't contain `glfwInit` function suitable for given platform. In other words, the problem seems to be compatibility one.

Comment: @Tsyvarev so how can I fix this compatibility issue then or even find out if it was a compatibility issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained [here](http://www.limeoats.com/clion-and-cmake.html)

1. Make `Findglfw3.cmake` file in `PROJECT/cmake/Modules/` which looks like

   ```
   # GLFW_FOUND
   # GLFW_INCLUDE_DIR
   # GLFW_LIBRARY

   set(FIND_GLFW_PATHS "F:\\C++\\ExternalLibraries\\GLFW")

   find_path(GLFW_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES GLFW/glfw3 GLFW/glfw3.h PATH_SUFFIXES include PATHS ${FIND_GLFW_PATHS})
   find_library(GLFW_LIBRARY NAMES glfw3 glfw3.a libglfw3 libglfw3.a PATH_SUFFIXES lib-mingw PATHS ${FIND_GLFW_PATHS})

   include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
   find_package_handle_standard_args(GLFW DEFAULT_MSG GLFW_LIBRARY GLFW_INCLUDE_DIR)

   mark_as_advanced(GLFW_INCLUDE_DIR GLFW_LIBRARY)
   ```
2. Define Module Path in `CMakeLists.txt`

   ```
   #Define module path
   list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cmake/Modules")
   ```
3. Also Link include directory and library with project in `CMakeLists.txt`

   ```
   #Define static GLFW libraries and header files
   find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED)
   include_directories(${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIR})
   ...
   target_link_libraries(Hatsudouki_core ${GLFW_LIBRARY})
   ```

Comment: Can we add external libraries to clion using Makefile

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to install `glfw` package. If you are using `MSYS2` then it can be installed using `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-glfw` on 64-bit windows and `pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-glfw` on 32-bit windows. And you need to use `find_package` to let the `cmake` locate the `glfw`  library automatically instead of manually locating them. If you are **not** using `MSYS2` then it might be little *difficult*. Check out this code.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(Hatsudouki_core)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(Hatsudouki_core main.cpp)

find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED) # Find the GLFW library
target_link_libraries(Hatsudouki_core PRIVATE glfw) # Finally, link to them.
```

I suggest you to use MSYS2 If you need pre-compiled libraries. It has a very good package manager called as `pacman`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I do not use or have MSYS2. Therefore, I tried the other suggestions in the comments. I thought there might be a solution without installing each library I want to use. I will try your suggestion if the other suggestions won't work.